# css columns, first column is not in same line as other columns

Tags: css

Using columns to display some data, though first column items are not on the same line as items in other columns, how could I have them all in line?

```
[let skils = \['javascript', 'react', 'git', 'github', 'html5', 'css3'\];][1]
```

```scss
.skills {
      columns: 3;
      @media only screen and (min-width: 940px) {
        columns: 2;
      }
   
      li {
        margin: 0;
        line-height: 1;
      }
    }
```

You can check how it looks in the image

Comment: Please attach your image. I don't see any image here!

Comment: Please also post the jsx or HTML, which you are trying to style

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want them all on the same line.  In which case use this

```css
ul.skills li {display:inline-block}
```

And if you want to remove the bullet then

```css
ul.skills {list-style:none}
```

You do need proper **HTML**, unless you are using some library or language to do it.